# Django URL changes but doesn't render the proper view

Tags: django, url, django-views

I have a url setup with the following view (the url is in the app and the app urls are included in the project):

```
url(r'^details/(?P<outage_id>\d+)/$', 'outage.views.outage_details'),

def outage_details(request, outage_id=1):
    outage_info = Outages.objects.filter(id=outage_id)
    return render_to_response('templates/outage/details.html', {'outage_info': outage_info}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

When I click on the link from `http://localhost:8000` the url in the browser changes to `http://localhost:8000/outage/details/1` as it should, but the view doesn't render the right template. The page stays the same. I don't get any errors, the url changes in the browser but the details.html template doesn't render. There is an outage in the DB with an ID of 1.

Any thoughts?

Comment: One issue i see is, `Outages.objects.filter(id=outage_id)` returns a queryset, and not an object. Is that what you want ?

Comment: I guess being so new to django, I don't know the answer to that. I do know that if I remove the query from the view and JUST render_to_response the template, it still only changes the url and doesn't actually render the template. Also, if I change the file name from details.html to something else but do not alter the view, the same thing happens. No errors.

Comment: You should post your entire urls.py. Probably your index view is catching all URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression `r'^details/(?P<outage_id>\d+)/$'` does not match the URL `http://localhost:8000/outage/details/1`. However, it should match the expression `r'^outage/details/(?P<outage_id>\d+)/$'`.

Perhaps, you can post your entire `urls.py` to find out which view is actually being called, since you don't get any errors. I suspect your home page is being called for all URLs.

Comment: Here is my url setup:

Comment: Well, my guess was right :) Change your first url pattern to: `url(r'^$', 'outage.views.show_outages'),`

Comment: Jeez! I stared at that file for an hour and never saw that I missed the $. Thanks for the extra set of eyes!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my url setup:

project/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', 'outage.views.show_outages'),
url(r'^inventory/', include('inventory.urls')),
url(r'^outage/', include('outage.urls')),
url(r'^login', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'templates/auth/login.html'}),
url(r'^logout', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/'}),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

)

outage/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^', 'outage.views.show_outages'),
url(r'^notes/(?P<outage_id>\d+)/$', 'outage.views.outage_notes', name='notes'),
```

)

I have since changed the details to notes, since I had another page in a different app with a details url and I didn't want it somehow confusing things.

Comment: Please edit your question, rather than adding this as an answer